# Gridview outside UpdatePanel not showing

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, updatepanel, itemcommand

I have an ItemCommand event in a button found in a listview.

```
    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
<ContentTemplate>
    <asp:ListView ID="systemsView" runat="server" 
        onitemcommand="systemsView_ItemCommand">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:Button ID="btnView" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("SYSTEM_DESC") %>' CommandArgument='<%# Eval("ROW_ID")%>'
                class="systemButtonStyle" />
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:ListView>
</ContentTemplate>                        
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

When the itemCommand is fired I want to bind another gridview which is not inside the update panel. The gridview is not showing when the event is fired. Any ideas how I could solve this problem please?

Comment: grid view should also be in update panel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `UpdatePanel`s only perform a PostBack on controls within their `ContentTemplate`, all controls that are expected to be updated by a Partial PostBack must be housed within the same `UpdatePanel`'s ContentTemplate.

If you need to update something outside of an `UpdatePanel` with an action that occurs within it's Partial PostBack, you will have to rethink your use of the `UpdatePanel`.

Two solutions:

- Add the other `GridView` to the `UpdatePanel`'s ContentTemplate.
- Remove the `UpdatePanel` entirely and use the normal PostBack.

Comment: I've added another update panel and worked as I wanted. Thanks

Comment: An alternative is to call a bit of javascript to click a button to populate the gridview outside the update panel. I do this all the time as I find pages with multiple update panels, sooner or later, do something weird.

Comment: Yeah, with modern jQuery, the UpdatePanel has been somewhat deprecated.